# show divs' 3 to 5 jQuery

Tags: jquery, pagination, slice, jquery-pagination

I am creating a tab content pagination. What I need here is I need to show and hide divs' according to the selected paginate item value. I need to show 3 divs in the content at a time. User can use pagination to paginate the other contents in the current tab.

I tried using `slice` and `lt`. When I going forward it is working fine. But I don't know how can I get those back when I reverse.

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="active" id="tab1">
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
    <div class="foo">Contents going here</div>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab2"></div
<div class="tab" id="tab3"></div>

<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('.foo').filter(':lt(' + sItems + '),:gt(' + sTo + ')').fadeOut(300);
```

I am passing `sItems` and `sTo` as variable values.

What I need is show divs' which is in between `sItems` and `sTo`. It can be 1 to 3, 4 to 6 etc, according to the pagination value selected.

Comment: What does the arguments mean?

Comment: it is the which div to which div content need to show. as an example if I select paginate number 2 I need to show divs from 4 to 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a  [Working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/5j5ft0k3/2/) , And the code is as below

```js
$(function() {
  $('div.foo').hide(); //initially hide all the div's on page load.


  $.each($('div.tab'), function() {
    var $currTab = $(this);

    //create Li tags dynamically
    var totalListToBuild = ($currTab.find('div.foo').length) / 3;
    for (var i = 0; i < totalListToBuild; i++) {
      $currTab.find('ul.pagination').append('<li><a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>');
    }

    $currTab.find('.pagination li a').on('click', function(e) { // bind events
      e.preventDefault();
      var currIndex = $(this).text();
      $currTab.find('div.foo').hide();
      var start = (currIndex * 3) - 3;
      var end = (currIndex * 3);

      $currTab.find(".foo").slice(start, end).show();
    });

    $currTab.find('.pagination li a:eq(0)').trigger('click'); //trigger first page click
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab active" id="tab1">
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 1</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 2</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 3</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 4</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 5</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 6</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 7</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 8</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 9</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 10</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 11</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 12</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 13</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 14</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 15</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 16</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 17</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 18</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 19</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 20</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 21</div>

  <ul class="pagination">

  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab2">
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 1</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 2</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 3</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 4</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 5</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 6</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 7</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 8</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 9</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 10</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 11</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 12</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 13</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 14</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 15</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 16</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 17</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 18</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 19</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 20</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 21</div>

  <ul class="pagination">

  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3">
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 1</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 2</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 3</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 4</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 5</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 6</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 7</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 8</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 9</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 10</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 11</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 12</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 13</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 14</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 15</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 16</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 17</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 18</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 19</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 20</div>
  <div class="foo">Contents going here 21</div>

  <ul class="pagination">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can i create pagination dynamically here. according to no of divs

Comment: Yes, then the only change would be you need to write a script that will generate the li tags dynamically.  So its like `(no of divs / 3) of li tags` that should append dynamically

Comment: Also you can use the links like next and prev, Because if there are 30 divs you'll end up showing 1 to 10 numbers in link..

Comment: DownVoters, Please care to comment my mistake, Let me correct myself.

Comment: can I create those li dynamically using jQuery before run the script. I tried it then this script is not working

Comment: @user2584538 I edited my answer to build the list dynamically plz check

Comment: I checked and this is working fine with first tab. But after for other tabs this not working. I mean tab2, tab3 and so forth

Comment: It is because we are dealing only with the first tab in the Jquery, Let me edit my answer to make it specific to each tabs.

Comment: Also tel me if all the tabs are open at the same time?? or its one at a time??

Comment: Need to use 1 tab at a time. When clicked on tab need to change the tab also. After pagination need to work for active tab.

Comment: So that means you will have to have separate paginators for each tab right??

Comment: Yes of course. I need initialize the pagination for each active tab.

Comment: OK I have update the logic to work for each tab. Have a check and let me know if you need more help. Also I have placed a paginator for each tab.. So it is operational only on those specific tab's.

Comment: :) enjoy your day, happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

Initial they are all showing. But when you click on one of the tabs, you will see the result.

```js
$( ".pagination li a" ).click(function() {
     index = $(this).parent().index();
     $( ".tab" ).hide();  
     $( ".tab" ).slice(index * 3, (index * 3) + 3).fadeIn();     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab" id="tab2">1</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab2">2</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3">3</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3">4</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3">5</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3">6</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3">7</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3">8</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3">9</div>


<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>   
</ul>
```

Comment: This is working great. This is what I looked for, Thanks.:)